# A way to override the <video> tag inside WYSIWYG field

Tags: media, wysiwyg, files

Facts:
 Media 7.x-2.0-alpha4+30-dev, File Entity 7.x-2.0-beta1
 Media WYSIWYG and Media WYSIWYG View Mode enabled

The source:

```
<p><video class="media-element file-default" controls="controls" data-fid="3" data-media-element="1"><source src="myvideo.avi" type="video/x-msvideo"></video>[[{"fid":"9","view_mode":"preview","fields":{"format":"preview","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"","field_file_image_title_text[und][0][value]":"","field_caption[und][0][value]":""},"type":"media","attributes":{"height":"180","width":"180","class":"media-element file-preview"}}]]</p>
```

I need to override the video tag by a certain hook in order to have a jwplayer as the default player.
Impossible to display it with media API hooks: as hook_media_wysiwyg_token_to_markup_alter.

UPDATE
I am able to set a new view mode using media wysiwyg view mode, however I need a custom display to help me customize the output.

[image]